# Removing empty quotes that only appear in DOM inspector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

In my contenteditable div, if the text is deleted (by a user), then immediately proceeded by a space (using the spacebar) and any text, empty quotes appear below the text in the DOM inspector (Chrome and Safari, tested).

Below is what's shown in the DOM inspector:

```
<div id="reminderTextEditable" contenteditable="true">
" test text"
""
</div>
```

If the text's leading space is removed in the div, the empty quotes are still there

```
<div id="reminderTextEditable" contenteditable="true">
"test text"
""
</div>
```

I tried the following code in an attempt to locate the empty quotes using Javascript, but it always alerts "1":

```
var list = document.getElementById('reminderTextEditable');
var list_items = list.childNodes;
alert(list_items.length);
```

Whatever the empty quotes are (whitespace?), they seem to be causing layout issues.

How can whatever is causing the empty quotes be removed?

Comment: Have you tried this in all browsers? I have had similar problems in Firefox, with <br/> tags, while the other browsers worked fine.

Comment: What are the layout issues? I can replicate the extra "" but I am trying to work out how it interferes with anything else on the page?

Comment: @Michael I've only tried in Chrome and Safari. Safari is the one I'm most concerned with. I'll look into the the <br/> issue. Thanks

Comment: @c01gat3 It seems to be interfering with an algorithm I'm using to calculate line widths, causing it to think the div's text is different (I think longer) than it really is.

Comment: This is till a problem in Chrome. Did you ever find a way around it?

Comment: @swelet I can't remember. Sorry. You might want to create your own question with your specific use-case. Maybe someone will have an easy workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit enter while editing, some browsers (like Firefox) add a 
 tag to achieve that effect. When you hit backspace, the cursor appears to erase the newline, but it does not erase the 
 tag. It is still there. A similar issue can happen with other whitespace characters.

Mozilla has a couple pretty detailed examples which have functions that delete extra tab indentations or new lines

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla.

To do it yourself you have to parse the innerHTML of the contenteditable element. If a node has no innerHTML (or is a text node with no nodeValue), delete it. Then go through the BR tags and if a tag is a BR and has no nextSibling delete it.

Comment: @user2782001Thanks. I'll look into this tonight. Another article that looked promising [was by Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/dom/). From the article, "A number of view options can be found in the settings, such as enabling and disabling the visibility of comment and whitespace nodes." I couldn't do too much with that info, though.

Comment: After looking at that page, I still couldn't find a way to fix my problem. The number of child nodes is always 1, and lacks any <BR> tags.

Comment: That is curious. You could try childNode[0].innerHTML.trim(" ").trim("\n") and see if it changes the length of the innerHTML.

Comment: Still no luck. innerHTML shows no signs of those empty quotes, nor does trimming it help. There is something peculiar about those text nodes. If they are whitespace-related, I'm thinking it's not going to be as simple as a newline or space character.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your best bet would be to adjust your layout so that it doesn't get affected by this issue, either through CSS or JS if the complexity warrants it.

Comment: Hey @zpr, I might be forced to do that in the end; but, for now it seems to be interfering with my JavaScript code I'm using to calculate line widths. It's copying the text from one div (white-space: pre-wrap) into another div (with white-space: nowrap) and runs an algorithm that adds delimiters to the text. Sometimes, the algorithm doesn't work right, and I think the empty quotes are the culprit :\